# Where exactly should I attach script in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have read about several ways to embed Javascript in HTML document.
First, in head section:

```
<head>
...
<script src="abc.js"></script>
</head>
```

Second, in the end of document's body:

```
<body>
<!-- content -->
<script src="abc.js"></script>
</body>
```

First way is more esthetic, but second version assures that all the items in DOM are loaded. I use HTML5 (but probably it doesn't matter)

Which way is better and why?

Comment: That would depend on the script !!

Comment: Script will modify DOM objcets, but not only. Let's say jQuery library.

Comment: Normally the jQuery library would be included in the head, and most people will load any other files containing jQuery in the head as well, as document.ready ensures there are no issues. Personally I often use a piece of javascript at the bottom of the page to load scripts dynamically, but not always, and again, it depends on the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is just a library of functions which aren't suppose to run when the page loads, you can safely put it in the head. Otherwise you need to wrap the code in `abc.js` with `window.onload` or `$(document).ready();` and then embed it in the head

Answer (score 2):

It depends on when you need the functionality in the script.
Before page load or else.
If it doesn't matter the second one in your example is better and more seciure since it allows the page content to load.
An error in the script may prevent for this to happen in before body case.

Comment: Where do you usually embed jQuery library?

Comment: Well I usually put them in the head but that's not reason for you to do it. It depends on what script code does

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on when you need script to execute if you need the page to be fully loaded or not. You can possibly put it in the head then execute a function with the `onload` event.